# Convert Weka tree into hierachyid for SQL hierachical table

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, weka, decision-tree

This question relates to the answer given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21804334/1688265).

I want to convert the output from a tree analysis in Weka into a hierarchical table of decision splits and leaf-values (as per the post linked above). I can parse the Weka output to extract the `fac`, `split` and `val` values but I'm struggling to parse the output and generate the correct `hierachyid` values.

First thing I note is that the tree description don't map one-to-one with the records in `decisions`. There are 20 lines in the Weka output and 21 records in the `decisions` table. This is because there are 11 leaf-nodes and 10 splits — each record in `decisions` is either a leaf-node or a split.

The Weka output lines correspond to either zero, one or two records in `decisions`. For example Ruleset #8 corresponds to no records; ruleset #1 corresponds to one record; ruleset #4 corresponds to two records.

I have the following example output

```
#   Ruleset
1   fac_a < 64
2   |   fac_d < 71.5
3   |   |   fac_a < 49.5
4   |   |   |   fac_d < 23.5 : 19.44 (13/43.71) [13/77.47]
5   |   |   |   fac_d >= 23.5 : 24.25 (32/23.65) [16/49.15]
6   |   |   fac_a >= 49.5 : 30.8 (10/17.68) [5/22.44]
7   |   fac_d >= 71.5 : 33.6 (25/53.05) [15/47.35]
8   fac_a >= 64
9   |   fac_d < 83.5
10  |   |   fac_a < 91
11  |   |   |   fac_e < 93.5
12  |   |   |   |   fac_d < 45 : 31.9 (16/23.25) [3/64.14]
13  |   |   |   |   fac_d >= 45
14  |   |   |   |   |   fac_e < 21.5 : 44.1 (5/16.58) [2/21.39]
15  |   |   |   |   |   fac_e >= 21.5
16  |   |   |   |   |   |   fac_a < 77.5 : 33.45 (4/2.89) [1/0.03]
17  |   |   |   |   |   |   fac_a >= 77.5 : 39.46 (7/10.21) [1/11.69]
18  |   |   |   fac_e >= 93.5 : 45.97 (2/8.03) [1/107.71]
19  |   |   fac_a >= 91 : 42.26 (9/9.57) [4/69.03]
20  |   fac_d >= 83.5 : 47.1 (9/30.24) [6/40.15]
```

I can determine if a Weak output line generates a `split` record in `decisions` by parsing for the substring `<`. I can determine if a line generates a `val` record in `decisions` by parsing for the `:`. However, I'm struggling to generate the appropriate `hierachyid` for both types of record in the `decisions` table.

The desired code to autogenerate for this example would be:

```
insert decisions values
  (cast('/0/' as hierarchyid), 'a', 64,null),
  (cast('/0/0/' as hierarchyid), 'd', 71.5,null),
  (cast('/0/0/0/' as hierarchyid), 'a', 49.5,null),
  (cast('/0/0/0/0/' as hierarchyid), 'd', 23.5,null),
  (cast('/0/0/0/0/0/' as hierarchyid), NULL, NULL,19.44),
  (cast('/0/0/0/0/1/' as hierarchyid), NULL, NULL, 24.25),
  (cast('/0/0/0/1/' as hierarchyid), NULL, NULL, 30.8),
  (cast('/0/0/1/' as hierarchyid), NULL, NULL, 33.6),
  (cast('/0/1/' as hierarchyid), 'd', 83.5,null),
  (cast('/0/1/0/' as hierarchyid), 'a', 91,null),
  (cast('/0/1/1/' as hierarchyid), NULL, NULL, 47.1),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/' as hierarchyid), 'e', 93.5,null),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/0/' as hierarchyid), 'd', 45,null),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/0/0/' as hierarchyid), null,null,31.9),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/0/1/' as hierarchyid), 'e', 21.5,null),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/0/1/0/' as hierarchyid), null,null,44.1),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/0/1/1/' as hierarchyid), 'a', 77.5,null),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/0/1/1/0/' as hierarchyid), NULL,NULL,33.45),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/0/1/1/1/' as hierarchyid), NULL,NULL,39.46),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/1/' as hierarchyid), NULL,NULL,45.97),
  (cast('/0/1/0/1/' as hierarchyid), NULL,NULL, 42.26);
go
```

What algorithm can I apply to generate the strings such as `/0/1/0/0/0/1/1/0/` that I need to attach to each `split` or `val` record in the `decisions` table?

Comment: Is this the only form you can get the data in? Do you have the option of using other languages to preprocess the data, or must it all be done entirely in SQL? Are the number of factors (here, a-e) fixed or variable, and what's the upper limit in either case? And just out of curiosity, what do the numbers after the colons mean?

Comment: The data output is the only form I have for the minute. I think I might be able to output as some Java objects but I haven't looked into that. I'm just looking for an algorithm (in any language) to parse these strings as I'm trying to produce a POC for the process

Comment: The number of factors won't be fixed in general. I don't know what the upper limit would be but I expect an algorithm that could cope with hundreds would be sufficient in all cases. The numbers after the colon aren't really relevant - the first number is the average response for that subgroup. The other numbers are train/test count/measure of variance, I believe.

Comment: (comment also posted at the original thread) My good friend Itzik Ben-Gan made a couple of suggestions. (Strings instead of hierarchyid, and a loop instead of recursion. He also noted that MAXRECURSION doesn't apply to the situation I had.) I've posted his solution here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/61f0b/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, each of your Weka output lines corresponds to 0, 1, or 2 INSERT statements. I'm restating some of what you said in case it helps you or someone else reading.

**Summary**

Output lines with < and without . are pure branch nodes (IFs) and correspond to 1 `INSERT` with null for the column [val].

Output lines with < and : are both branch and assignment nodes, so they correspond to 2 `INSERT`s. One with null [val], and one with the hierarchyid extended by `0/` and with non-null [val].

Output lines with >= and without . are ELSE nodes in your tree. The >= comparison information is redundant in your source and those lines require no INSERT statement.

In this example, no `INSERT` statement is needed for the >= branching (source lines 8, 13, 15), because the >= condition is necessarily true at that point in the decision tree. Those lines of your output are like ELSE statements, where you've redundantly stated what must be true about the factor value at that point. (The decisions could be made correctly even without the ">= ##.#" information from the tree in those lines.)

**Algorithm outline**

Go through your Weka output in order.

1. If the line you're at is indented from the previous one, `INSERT` once (append '0\' to the hierarchyid) for the decision (put NULL in [val]),
2. If the Weka line has also got `:` in it, `INSERT` another row in the table (appending a second `0\`) for the assignment
3. If the line you're at is not indented from the previous one, skip it if it has no `:` in it
4. If it has `:` and is an assignment, find it's "sibling" in the decision tree (the most recent row above it at the same indentation level). The sibling's hierarchyid will end in '0\', because it's a < comparison. Change the `0\` to `1\` and `INSERT` with a non-null [val].

Hope that helps and can be done practically from what you have.

Here's another set of INSERT statements that reference the line of your Weka output.

```
create table decisions (
  did hierarchyid primary key,
  fac char,
  split decimal(10,4),
  val decimal(10,4),
  sourceline int
)

insert decisions values
  (cast('/0/' as hierarchyid), 'a', 64,null,1), 
  (cast('/0/0/' as hierarchyid), 'd', 71.5,null,2),
  (cast('/0/0/0/' as hierarchyid), 'a', 49.5,null,3),
  (cast('/0/0/0/0/' as hierarchyid), 'd', 23.5,null,4),
  (cast('/0/0/0/0/0/' as hierarchyid), NULL, NULL,19.44,4),
  (cast('/0/0/0/0/1/' as hierarchyid), NULL, NULL, 24.25,5),
  (cast('/0/0/0/1/' as hierarchyid), NULL, NULL, 30.8,6),
  (cast('/0/0/1/' as hierarchyid), NULL, NULL, 33.6,7),
  (cast('/0/1/' as hierarchyid), 'd', 83.5,null,9),
  (cast('/0/1/0/' as hierarchyid), 'a', 91,null,10),
  (cast('/0/1/1/' as hierarchyid), NULL, NULL, 47.1,20),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/' as hierarchyid), 'e', 93.5,null,11),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/0/' as hierarchyid), 'd', 45,null,12),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/0/0/' as hierarchyid), null,null,31.9,12),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/0/1/' as hierarchyid), 'e', 21.5,null,14),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/0/1/0/' as hierarchyid), null,null,44.1,14),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/0/1/1/' as hierarchyid), 'a', 77.5,null,16),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/0/1/1/0/' as hierarchyid), NULL,NULL,33.45,16),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/0/1/1/1/' as hierarchyid), NULL,NULL,39.46,17),
  (cast('/0/1/0/0/1/' as hierarchyid), NULL,NULL,45.97,18),
  (cast('/0/1/0/1/' as hierarchyid), NULL,NULL, 42.26,19);
```

Comment: I've edited the algorithm a little but I haven't yet quite implemented a working version of it. This is an extremely useful pointer though, thanks Steve. I'll post once I achieve my goal

Comment: I'm struggling to keep track of the value of `hierachyid` as I follow the algorithm. Can this be done by scanning the Weka output in a single pass? I feel like I'm taking the wrong approach to parsing the tree structure in table format

Comment: How malleable is the Weka output? If the ruleset were this, it would be one easy pass: http://i.imgur.com/yJQWjJZ.png (image has a typo - 2 row #5s - sorry)

Comment: Also I think a typo in the last row where `83.5 :` should be omitted

Comment: I was able to modify this approach and produce a working algorithm. I'm in the process of writing that algorithm up, which I will include as a seperate answer for reference.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is no need to cast every line of a values clause (or set of unions) to the new data type--just the first line. In fact, since you're inserting to a table, you don't need to cast at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's SQL code that may work to turn your Weka output into the rows for the [decisions] table.

Obviously, SQL isn't the natural language to use, but it's what I had open and handy near the rest of the SQL for this question. Ultimately, they key idea is to implement a stack to keep track of the hierarchy. This is terribly kludgy, so I'd examine and test it well before using the idea in whatever language you use for your data-munging script. The overall idea isn't as awful as this looks. The worst of the code is string manipulation; that can be slicked up a great deal if you use a language with regular expression support.

I also junked the hierarchyid type, following Itzik's improvements (noted in the other thread).

Hope this helps.

You'll note that I make no use of the indentation in the Weka output. Instead, I'm making relatively strong assumptions about the nature of the rules and their order. (Every new nested comparison uses the < operator, for example, and a >= with the same value appears later. I also make assumptions about exact numbers of spaces and names like fac_x, some of which the use of regular expressions will obviate.)

```
create table ruleset (
  id int primary key,
  therule varchar(200)
);

insert into ruleset values
(1,'fac_a < 64'),
(2,'|   fac_d < 71.5'),
(3,'|   |   fac_a < 49.5'),
(4,'|   |   |   fac_d < 23.5 : 19.44 (13/43.71) [13/77.47]'),
(5,'|   |   |   fac_d >= 23.5 : 24.25 (32/23.65) [16/49.15]'),
(6,'|   |   fac_a >= 49.5 : 30.8 (10/17.68) [5/22.44]'),
(7,'|   fac_d >= 71.5 : 33.6 (25/53.05) [15/47.35]'),
(8,'fac_a >= 64'),
(9,'|   fac_d < 83.5'),
(10,'|   |   fac_a < 91'),
(11,'|   |   |   fac_e < 93.5'),
(12,'|   |   |   |   fac_d < 45 : 31.9 (16/23.25) [3/64.14]'),
(13,'|   |   |   |   fac_d >= 45'),
(14,'|   |   |   |   |   fac_e < 21.5 : 44.1 (5/16.58) [2/21.39]'),
(15,'|   |   |   |   |   fac_e >= 21.5'),
(16,'|   |   |   |   |   |   fac_a < 77.5 : 33.45 (4/2.89) [1/0.03]'),
(17,'|   |   |   |   |   |   fac_a >= 77.5 : 39.46 (7/10.21) [1/11.69]'),
(18,'|   |   |   fac_e >= 93.5 : 45.97 (2/8.03) [1/107.71]'),
(19,'|   |   fac_a >= 91 : 42.26 (9/9.57) [4/69.03]'),
(20,'|   fac_d >= 83.5 : 47.1 (9/30.24) [6/40.15]')
go

declare @ruleid int = 0;
declare @rulevar char;
declare @rulecomp decimal(10,4);
declare @ruleassign varchar(200);
declare @last int = (select max(id) from ruleset);
declare @rule varchar(200);
declare @resultindentlevel int = 0;

declare @stack table (
  id int identity(1,1) primary key,
  hier varchar(200),
  resultindentlevel int
);
insert into @stack values ('',0);

declare @results table (
  hier varchar(200),
  line varchar(200)
);

while @ruleid < @last begin

  set @ruleid += 1;
  set @rule = (select therule+space(1) from ruleset where id=@ruleid);

  declare @c char = case when @rule like '%[<]%' then '0' else '1' end;
  if @rule not like '%[<:]%' continue;

  declare @varpos int = charindex('f',@rule)+4;
  set @rulevar = substring(@rule,@varpos,1);
  set @rulecomp =
    substring(@rule,@varpos+4,charindex(space(1),@rule,@varpos+5)-@varpos-4);
  declare @peek varchar(200) = 
    (select top (1) hier from @stack order by id desc)
  --select * from @stack;
  if @rule not like '%>%' begin -- handle new condition
    set @peek += @c;
    if exists (select hier from @results where hier=@peek)
       set @peek=left(@peek,len(@peek)-1)+'1';
    insert into @results
      select @peek,@peek+'|'+@rulevar+'|'+ltrim(str(@rulecomp,15,4))+'||';
    insert into @stack values (@peek,0);
  end
  declare @colon int = charindex(':',@rule);
  if @colon > 0 begin -- handle assignment value 
    set @ruleassign = substring(@rule,@colon+2,200);
      insert into @results select @peek+@c,@peek+@c + '|'+@rulevar+'||'+@ruleassign;
  end
  if @rule like '%>%' delete from @stack where id = (select max(id) from @stack)
end;

update @results set line = ''''+replace(rtrim(line),'|',''',''')+'''';
update @results set line = replace(line,'''''','NULL');
select line from @results;
go
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a version for you that will allow any number of factors and tree depth (with only slight modifications necessary to demo more). I don't know what the performance will be like, but it is potentially good if appropriate indexes are added.

First we load the raw data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.WekaTree (
   ID int,
   Ruleset varchar(70)
);

INSERT dbo.WekaTree (ID, Ruleset)
VALUES
   (1, 'fac_a < 64'),
   (2, '|   fac_d < 71.5'),
   (3, '|   |   fac_a < 49.5'),
   (4, '|   |   |   fac_d < 23.5 : 19.44 (13/43.71) [13/77.47]'),
   (5, '|   |   |   fac_d >= 23.5 : 24.25 (32/23.65) [16/49.15]'),
   (6, '|   |   fac_a >= 49.5 : 30.8 (10/17.68) [5/22.44]'),
   (7, '|   fac_d >= 71.5 : 33.6 (25/53.05) [15/47.35]'),
   (8, 'fac_a >= 64'),
   (9, '|   fac_d < 83.5'),
   (10, '|   |   fac_a < 91'),
   (11, '|   |   |   fac_e < 93.5'),
   (12, '|   |   |   |   fac_d < 45 : 31.9 (16/23.25) [3/64.14]'),
   (13, '|   |   |   |   fac_d >= 45'),
   (14, '|   |   |   |   |   fac_e < 21.5 : 44.1 (5/16.58) [2/21.39]'),
   (15, '|   |   |   |   |   fac_e >= 21.5'),
   (16, '|   |   |   |   |   |   fac_a < 77.5 : 33.45 (4/2.89) [1/0.03]'),
   (17, '|   |   |   |   |   |   fac_a >= 77.5 : 39.46 (7/10.21) [1/11.69]'),
   (18, '|   |   |   fac_e >= 93.5 : 45.97 (2/8.03) [1/107.71]'),
   (19, '|   |   fac_a >= 91 : 42.26 (9/9.57) [4/69.03]'),
   (20, '|   fac_d >= 83.5 : 47.1 (9/30.24) [6/40.15]')
;
```

Then we parse this into a `RuleSets` table that encodes the tree in the form needed for a data-probing query:

```
WITH A AS (SELECT A = 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
B AS (SELECT A = 1 FROM A, A B),
C AS (SELECT A = 1 FROM B, B C),
N AS (SELECT Num = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM C, C D),
Data AS (
   SELECT
      ID,
      Ruleset,
      Depth = Len(Ruleset) - Len(Replace(Ruleset, '|', '')) + 1,
      Data = Replace(Ruleset, '|   ', '')
   FROM
      dbo.WekaTree
), Depths AS (
   SELECT
      D.ID,
      D.Ruleset,
      D.Depth,
      F.Factor,
      O.Operator,
      V.Value,
      V.Remainder
   FROM
      Data D
      CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT
            Factor = Left(D.Data, CharIndex(' ', D.Data) - 1),
            OperatorString = Substring(D.Data, CharIndex(' ', D.Data) + 1, 8000)
      ) F
      CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT
            Operator = Left(F.OperatorString, CharIndex(' ', F.OperatorString) - 1),
            ValueString = Substring(F.OperatorString, CharIndex(' ', F.OperatorString) + 1, 8000)
      ) O
      CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT
            Value = Convert(decimal(10,2), Left(O.ValueString, CharIndex(' ', O.ValueString + ' ') - 1)),
            Remainder = Substring(O.ValueString, CharIndex(' ', O.ValueString + ' ') + 3, 8000)
      ) V
)
SELECT
   D.ID,
   D.Remainder,
   H.Factor,
   H.Operator,
   H.Value
INTO
   dbo.Rulesets
FROM
   Depths D
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT
         X.Factor,
         X.Operator,
         Value = Min(X.Value * M.Multiplier) * M.Multiplier
      FROM
         N
         CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT TOP 1
               *
            FROM
               Depths D2
            WHERE
               N.Num = D2.Depth
               AND D.ID >= D2.ID
            ORDER BY
               D2.ID DESC
         ) X
         CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT 1 WHERE X.Operator = '<'
            UNION ALL SELECT -1 WHERE X.Operator = '>='
         ) M (Multiplier)
      WHERE
         N.Num <= D.Depth
      GROUP BY
         X.Factor,
         X.Operator,
         M.Multiplier
   ) H
WHERE
   D.Remainder <> ''
ORDER BY
   D.ID,
   H.Factor,
   H.Operator
;
```

Here's what the resulting data looks like (only leaf node IDs are needed and present):

```
ID   Remainder                   Factor Operator Value
---- --------------------------- ------ -------- ---------------------------------------
4    19.44 (13/43.71) [13/77.47] fac_a  <        49.5
4    19.44 (13/43.71) [13/77.47] fac_d  <        23.5
5    24.25 (32/23.65) [16/49.15] fac_a  <        49.5
5    24.25 (32/23.65) [16/49.15] fac_d  <        71.5
5    24.25 (32/23.65) [16/49.15] fac_d  >=       23.5
6    30.8 (10/17.68) [5/22.44]   fac_a  <        64.0
6    30.8 (10/17.68) [5/22.44]   fac_a  >=       49.5
6    30.8 (10/17.68) [5/22.44]   fac_d  <        71.5
7    33.6 (25/53.05) [15/47.35]  fac_a  <        64.0
7    33.6 (25/53.05) [15/47.35]  fac_d  >=       71.5
12   31.9 (16/23.25) [3/64.14]   fac_a  <        91.0
12   31.9 (16/23.25) [3/64.14]   fac_a  >=       64.0
12   31.9 (16/23.25) [3/64.14]   fac_d  <        45.0
12   31.9 (16/23.25) [3/64.14]   fac_e  <        93.5
14   44.1 (5/16.58) [2/21.39]    fac_a  <        91.0
14   44.1 (5/16.58) [2/21.39]    fac_a  >=       64.0
14   44.1 (5/16.58) [2/21.39]    fac_d  <        83.5
14   44.1 (5/16.58) [2/21.39]    fac_d  >=       45.0
14   44.1 (5/16.58) [2/21.39]    fac_e  <        21.5
16   33.45 (4/2.89) [1/0.03]     fac_a  <        77.5
16   33.45 (4/2.89) [1/0.03]     fac_a  >=       64.0
16   33.45 (4/2.89) [1/0.03]     fac_d  <        83.5
16   33.45 (4/2.89) [1/0.03]     fac_d  >=       45.0
16   33.45 (4/2.89) [1/0.03]     fac_e  <        93.5
16   33.45 (4/2.89) [1/0.03]     fac_e  >=       21.5
17   39.46 (7/10.21) [1/11.69]   fac_a  <        91.0
17   39.46 (7/10.21) [1/11.69]   fac_a  >=       77.5
17   39.46 (7/10.21) [1/11.69]   fac_d  <        83.5
17   39.46 (7/10.21) [1/11.69]   fac_d  >=       45.0
17   39.46 (7/10.21) [1/11.69]   fac_e  <        93.5
17   39.46 (7/10.21) [1/11.69]   fac_e  >=       21.5
18   45.97 (2/8.03) [1/107.71]   fac_a  <        91.0
18   45.97 (2/8.03) [1/107.71]   fac_a  >=       64.0
18   45.97 (2/8.03) [1/107.71]   fac_d  <        83.5
18   45.97 (2/8.03) [1/107.71]   fac_e  >=       93.5
19   42.26 (9/9.57) [4/69.03]    fac_a  >=       91.0
19   42.26 (9/9.57) [4/69.03]    fac_d  <        83.5
20   47.1 (9/30.24) [6/40.15]    fac_a  >=       64.0
20   47.1 (9/30.24) [6/40.15]    fac_d  >=       83.5
```

And I've created some fake sample probe data. Note that here, the factors are in *rows*, not in *columns*. If you have `fac_a` through `fac_z` and then `fac_aa` through `fac_zz`, you're still in business.

```
WITH A AS (SELECT A = 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
B AS (SELECT A = 1 FROM A, A B),
C AS (SELECT A = 1 FROM B, B C),
N AS (SELECT Num = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) - 1 FROM B, C, C D)
SELECT
   N.Num,
   F.Factor,
   V.Value
INTO
   dbo.LookupData
FROM
   N
   CROSS JOIN (VALUES
      (1, 'fac_a'), (4, 'fac_b'), (16, 'fac_c'), (64, 'fac_d'), (256, 'fac_e')
   ) F (Mult, Factor)
   INNER JOIN (VALUES
      (0, 25), (1, 50), (2, 75), (3, 100)
   ) V (Pattern, Value)
      ON (N.Num / F.Mult) % 4 = V.Pattern
WHERE
   N.Num <= 1023
;
```

Example probe data:

```
Num    Factor Value
------ ------ -----------
0      fac_a  25
0      fac_b  25
0      fac_c  25
0      fac_d  25
0      fac_e  25
1      fac_a  50
1      fac_b  25
1      fac_c  25
1      fac_d  25
1      fac_e  25
2      fac_a  75
2      fac_b  25
2      fac_c  25
2      fac_d  25
2      fac_e  25
...
1021   fac_a  50
1021   fac_b  100
1021   fac_c  100
1021   fac_d  100
1021   fac_e  100
1022   fac_a  75
1022   fac_b  100
1022   fac_c  100
1022   fac_d  100
1022   fac_e  100
1023   fac_a  100
1023   fac_b  100
1023   fac_c  100
1023   fac_d  100
1023   fac_e  100
```

Finally, here's the query that shows the innermost ID row from the Weka Tree that matches the conditions of the probe row. Please keep in mind that I have not created suitable indexes here, and you should do so. Using the values 25, 50, 75, and 100 for each of the factors, this creates every possibly combination:

```
WITH Matches AS (
   SELECT
      L.Num,
      R.ID
   FROM
      dbo.LookupData L
      INNER JOIN dbo.Rulesets R
         ON L.Factor = R.Factor
   GROUP BY
      L.Num,
      R.ID
   HAVING
      Min(CASE WHEN (
               R.Operator = '<'
               AND L.Value < R.Value
            ) OR (
               R.Operator = '>='
               AND L.Value >= R.Value
            ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
)
SELECT
   L.*,
   W.*
FROM
   dbo.LookupData L
   INNER JOIN Matches M
      ON L.Num = M.Num
   LEFT JOIN dbo.WekaTree W
      ON M.ID = W.ID
ORDER BY
   L.Num
;
```

Example results:

```
Num Factor Value ID Ruleset
--- ------ ----- -- -------------------------------------------------------
0   fac_a  25    5  |   |   |   fac_d >= 23.5 : 24.25 (32/23.65) [16/49.15]
0   fac_b  25    5  |   |   |   fac_d >= 23.5 : 24.25 (32/23.65) [16/49.15]
0   fac_c  25    5  |   |   |   fac_d >= 23.5 : 24.25 (32/23.65) [16/49.15]
0   fac_d  25    5  |   |   |   fac_d >= 23.5 : 24.25 (32/23.65) [16/49.15]
0   fac_e  25    5  |   |   |   fac_d >= 23.5 : 24.25 (32/23.65) [16/49.15]
1   fac_a  50    6  |   |   fac_a >= 49.5 : 30.8 (10/17.68) [5/22.44]
1   fac_b  25    6  |   |   fac_a >= 49.5 : 30.8 (10/17.68) [5/22.44]
1   fac_c  25    6  |   |   fac_a >= 49.5 : 30.8 (10/17.68) [5/22.44]
1   fac_d  25    6  |   |   fac_a >= 49.5 : 30.8 (10/17.68) [5/22.44]
1   fac_e  25    6  |   |   fac_a >= 49.5 : 30.8 (10/17.68) [5/22.44]
2   fac_a  75    12 |   |   |   |   fac_d < 45 : 31.9 (16/23.25) [3/64.14]
2   fac_b  25    12 |   |   |   |   fac_d < 45 : 31.9 (16/23.25) [3/64.14]
2   fac_c  25    12 |   |   |   |   fac_d < 45 : 31.9 (16/23.25) [3/64.14]
2   fac_d  25    12 |   |   |   |   fac_d < 45 : 31.9 (16/23.25) [3/64.14]
2   fac_e  25    12 |   |   |   |   fac_d < 45 : 31.9 (16/23.25) [3/64.14]
```

Please feel free to ask any questions you like--I'd be happy to help you get this working in a test against your own data. I can't promise instant response but I generally do check for activity on SO daily so would at least be able to respond within a day or two in most cases.

## [See a live demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/71b82/1)